# Distribution question solution explanation.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

[image]

Could someone please explain this solution (in the picture below) to the above question in a simpler way? For instance, why do we say that An is a decreasing sequence since Zn is increasing? And why do we use the word "consequently" in the next sentence? What about the previous sentence leads us to the next sentence that we had to use the word "consequently"? And could someone also please explain the last sentence in the solution which starts with "where the second inequality...." in a simpler way? Help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1. Decreasing sequence allows us to use continuity of probability measure. 

2. $Z_n$ is increasing with $n$, since we add non-negative values, and hence we decrease possible $w$: $\{w: Z_n(w) \le a\}$.

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand what you mean by "hence we decrease possible w". And could you also please explain what does the term "Zn(w)" mean? What does the "w" in the brackets mean? Probability is not my strong subject.

Comment: $Z_n$ is a random variable, i.e. measurable map $Z_n : \Omega \to [0, 1]$. Decrease possible $w$, i.e. we reduce amount of possible $w: Z_n(w) \le a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sequence of sets $\{A_n\}$ is *decreasing* if for each $n$, $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$. $Z_n$ is an increasing sequence of random variables because
$$
Z_{n+1}-Z_n = \frac2{3^{n+1}}X_{n+1}\geqslant 0.
$$
It follows from the "continuity from below" property of measures that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P(A_n) = \mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n\right)$.

As for the inequality in question, it follows directly from the definition of $Y$ as the pointwise limit of $Z_n$ (as functions), and the fact that an increasing sequence of real numbers that is bounded above converges to its supremum.